# how to initialize and give reference to an imageButton in a fragmenActivity class

Tags: java, android-studio, android-imagebutton

**i am new into android, i am trying to give reference to an imageButton using findbyView  but it keep saying that cannot resolve findbyView, i undrstood that i can only use find by view only in activy class, what other ways to initialize an imageButton please **

Answer (score 0):

As per your question on How to Instantiate the image button class, am sure you must have imported your button class.  if yes then this is the recommended way of doing it

`ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageid);`  an it always works

Answer (score 0):

Override onCreateView(..) method in FragmentActivity and use inflator to inflate your vies and use that view to get all element

```
 @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_layout, container, false);
            imageButton= (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imgbtnid);
}
```